# What does "object's identity must change" mean in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular

I am reading this [Angular doc](https://angular.io/guide/class-binding#binding-to-multiple-css-classes), it says:

> With any object-like expression—such as object, Array, Map, or Set—the identity of the object must change for Angular to update the class list. Updating the property without changing object identity has no effect.

So, how do I change an object't identity?

Thanks.

Comment: You create a new object and copy over all the properties. `const newObj = {...oldObj};`

Comment: Thanks @Evert. So if I want to change one item in my class list, I have to assign it to a new class list?

Comment: I think it means immutability.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The wording there is slightly unfortunate. You can't really *change* an object's identity - the identity is *that object*. It's like trying to make X not X. What it means is that a new object or array needs to be created for Angular to detect it as different. For a tiny example in vanilla JS:

```js
const isSameObject = (obj1, obj2) => obj1 === obj2;

console.log(isSameObject({}, {})); // false, different objects

const someObj = {};
const sameReferenceToSomeObj = someObj;
sameReferenceToSomeObj.newProp = 'newVal';
console.log(isSameObject(someObj, sameReferenceToSomeObj)); // true, same object
```

For Angular to detect a change the identity on a property, the property value must be changed to a new value, rather than having the old value mutated. The second example in the snippet above is an example of how *not* to do things in Angular; mutating an object doesn't change its identity (it's still the same object), so if you did that in Angular, it would see that the old object on the property is `===` to the new object on the property, and would not produce a visual change as a result.

Create an entirely new object instead, with the desired properties, and put that object on the component, and then Angular will be able to see that the new object is not `===` to the old object, and take the appropriate action as a result, eg

```
this.theClassList = { ...this.theClassList, newProperty: 'foo' }
```

and not

```
const newClassList = this.theClassList;
newClassList.newProperty = 'foo';
this.theClassList = newClassList;
```

Comment: This is the answer for me. Thanks @CertainPerformance!